# Perform a query on EF but exclude specific elements from the results

Tags: entity-framework

Let's say I have to manage gates and the availability of these gates.

Here is my model:

```
public class Gate
{
    public int GateID { get; set; }
    public string GateName { get; set; }
}

public class GateNA  ---> NA: NotAvailable
{
    public int GateNAID { get; set; }
    public int GateID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Now lets say I have the following sample data:

**For Gates:**

GateID: 1
GateName: "San Antonio Gate"

GateID: 2
GateName: "Santa Fe Gate"

GateID: 3
GateName: "Santa Maria Gate"

**These gates are not available at a specific date (>> GateNA class):**

GateIDNA: 1
GateID: 2
Date: 2012/06/01

GateIDNA: 2
GateID: 1
Date: 2012/08/08

I'm able to retrieve all the gates beginning with "Santa" like this:

```
var gateRepository = unitOfWork.Create<Gate>();
var gates = gateRepository.Find(m => m.GateName.Contains("Santa"));
```

**My question is** how can I retrieve all the gates beginning with "Santa" AND AVAILABLE between 2012/06/01 and 2012/06/05. So we have to check in GateNA...

The result should be here only one element: the GateID 3.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you restructure your class like:

```
public class Gate
{
    public int GateID { get; set; }
    public string GateName { get; set; }
    public List<GateNA> NotAvailableDates { get; set; }
}

public class GateNA  ---> NA: NotAvailable
{
    public int GateNAID { get; set; }
    public int GateID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
var gates = gateRepository.Find(
    m => m.GateName.Contains("Santa") && 
   (m.NotAvailableDates.Find(
        d => d.Date==new DateTime(2012,06,01)
   )==null
);
```

Comment: Ok, this was a EF question and I thought like it was a C# question. And I don't know if this will break the connection between EF and the model, you are free to downvote if this won't work then :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is adding navigation property for `GateNA` collection to your `Gate` entity and use it in the query:

```
gateRepository.Find(m => m.GateName.Contains("Santa") && 
                         !m.GateNAs.Any(g => g.Date == selectedDate));
```

If you don't add the property you will have to perform manual join in LINQ query.